# A program that determines if the user feed is integer of decimal

Tags: c#, numbers, try-catch

I'm doing a school assignment in which  we are assigned to make a program that asks the user to input a number. It then changes the input into a number and determines if the number is an integer or a decimal. If not possible, it says this to the user. The program cannot have errors that the users input can cause.

My problem is the part where the program determines if the feed is an integer or a decimal, if I input an integer, it says the number is integer and decimal, if I input a decimal, it ends in an error. The program never reaches `catch (Exception)`  if the input is wrong.

```
public static void ITellYouYourNumbers(float number)
{
    try
    {
        float d = number;
        int isInt = (int)d;
        Console.WriteLine("The number is a integer");

        float isFloat = (float)d;
        Console.WriteLine("The number is a decimal");
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Your input cannot be changed into a number. Try again.");
        Console.ReadLine();
        throw;
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Write a number");
    float num = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    ITellYouYourNumbers(num);
}
```

I've tried determening the `d` in different ways, such as:

```
decimal d = number
    Console.WriteLine((d % 1) == 0);
    d = number
    Console.WriteLine((d % 1) == 0);
```

and

`(d % 1) < epsilon`

but nothing I've tried works. If the input is integer, it shows as an integer and decimal, if I input a decimal, it says that an error occured in the `float num = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());` , but it doesn't show up as an error in the program itself.

Comment: I suggest using the various number `TryParse` methods

Comment: To explain why you do don't see an exception: casting a float to an int is perfectly valid and will return the integer part of the number (rounding towards zero). For details see the chapter "explicit numerical conversions" in the [language specification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/conversions)

Answer (score 0):

First, float.Parse() will fail with an exception if the string you put in can not be parsed as a float (beware of the high and low limits too, there are minimum and maximum values) and the exception will not be stopped by the catch since it was not generated in the try-catch block.

Second, a float can always be casted to an int.

Third, you are casting d to a float while d is already a float so why would it not work ?

Fourth, you are putting your float parameter (called "number") in another float inside the function (called "d"). While not wrong technically speaking, it bothers me to duplicate a value when you have no plan to modify either instance of it.

If you can modify the main, call directly your ITellYouYourNumbers function and put the string in without trying to parse it. If I understand the instructions of your exercise correctly, all you have to do is check that
1/ The string is not empty even after removing all blank characters at both ends.
2/ After trimming, it contains only numbers and at most one '.' or ',' character.
3/ If it contains a '.' or ',', it is a decimal. Otherwise, it is an integer.

If you are actually supposed to cast the input as a number, you can check if it represents an integer by exploiting the fact that `int x = (int)y` will get the integer part of y and put it in x.
After that, you just have to check whether x==y or not.

Comment: I think I am supposed to cast the input as a number, as we are supposed to be using the try-catch method. How exactly should I then modify the main so that the error does now occur?

Comment: Pass the input string to the function and parse it there, or if your instructions impose to have only a float parameter in the function, add a try-catch in the main.